# How To use COUNTIF, but exclude if those results also have text in another column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm relatively new to Google sheets but I was hoping you could help me out.

Let's say I have the following information in a table:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| $14.99 |  |
| $14.99 | Yes |
| $12.99 |  |
| $13.99 | Yes |
| $14.99 | Yes |

I want to use COUNTIF to count the number of times column A has $14.99, BUT I only want to know if in those same results, Column B doesn't contain "Yes". (So in this case the total count should be 1)

Hopefully, that makes sense. Any idea which formula I should use?

Comment: You said your total count of instances where Col A contains $14.99 but Col B *does not* contain "Yes" is 2. I count 1. So it's unclear if you made an error in your count or in your explanation. Please double-check and adjust your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment to your original post. Assuming that your posted count of matches was off and that it should be 1, this formula will produce the correct count:

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A,14.99,B2:B,"<>Yes")`

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I messed up my own calculation. You are right.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear this solved your problem. Please take a moment to close this post by marking my answer post as "Best Answer." Thanks.

Comment: At least I gave you a thumbs up.